# How to take a screenshot with the Night Light tint on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, screenshot

When you take a screenshot on Ubuntu 18.04 (using Gnome Screenshot), the yellow tint from the Night Light is removed from the output screenshot image.

I would like the output screenshot image to **include** the yellow Night Light tint. How can this be achieved?

Comment: is this an option on your screen? if so, I think it can not appear on the software, is it?

Comment: For my personnal use, i use Shutter 0.93.1 shutter-project.org